# POP3 клиент на C++ с использованием SSL

Tags: visual-c++, ssl, pop3

Пишу программу для получения почты по протоколу POP3. Когда учился в универе писал такого клиента, просто создавал сокет, коннектился к pop.mail.ru на 110 порту и слал команды. Но сейчас mail.ru (да и прочие почтовые серверы) использует SSL, и поэтому при коннекте сокета на сервер получаю ошибку 10060 "Превышен интервал ожидания для подключения". Нашел в гугле совет использовать библиотеку OpenSSL, но так и не понял как её для этого использовать. Прошу совета или пинка в нужную сторону)

Comment: Если ошибка при коннекте - значит неправильный IP (по-моему там IP передаётся, а не имя) или порт. Возможно нужно через прокси коннектится (если интернет через прокси)

Comment: Да, проблема с коннектом была в прокси-сервере. Но вот вопрос, даже после коннекта, я не могу работать с почтой, т.к. сервер требует SSL. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Здравствуйте, Вы решили этот вопрос?